# Using PHP date_default_timezone_set for multiple states not working as expected

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

Ok so I have some code in the same PHP file which I'm trying to set the default timezone for two states in Australia.

ok First the Adelaide time:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Adelaide');
$currentTime = strtotime(date("H:i"));
echo $currentTime;
```

Now the queensland time

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Queensland');
$currentTimeQld = strtotime(date("H:i"));
echo "<br />" . $currentTimeQld;
```

SO queensland is 30 mins behind adelaide during daylight savings, so I would expect the strtotime value to be less.
But I get the same output for both echo statements.

Output:
1507506480
1507506480
Anyone know why.
Thanks

> UPDATE: The reason why I want to use strtotime is so I can calculate
>   wether or not to display a open or closed tag
>
> ```
> $openTime = strtotime("08:30");
> $closeTime = strtotime("17:30");
> $openCloseTag = ($currentTime >= $openTime && $currentTime <= $closeTime) ? '<span class="openTag">Open</span>' : '<span class="closeTag">Closed</span>';
> ```

Comment: The reason could be that Queensland timezone is deprecated, as per http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.australia.php.

Comment: @Jixone Hi. I tried using `date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');` but still the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a DateTime object. Solved your case like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Adelaide');
$currentTime= new DateTime();
$currentTime->setTimestamp(strtotime(date("H:i")));
echo $currentTime->format('H:i');


date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Queensland');
$currentTimeQld = new DateTime();
$currentTimeQld->setTimestamp(strtotime(date("H:i")));
echo "<br />" . $currentTimeQld->format('H:i');
```

Output:

```
12:58
12:28 -- 30 mins difference
```

After reading the documentation, I found out that there is no such thing as a timestamp relative to a timezone. So in this case, we will use timezone `offset`. Getting the timezone offset:

```
$currentTime= new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Australia/Adelaide'));
echo $currentTime->getTimestamp() ."-". $currentTime->getOffset() ."<br />";

$currentTimeQld = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Australia/Queensland'));
echo $currentTimeQld->getTimestamp() ."-". $currentTimeQld->getOffset() ."<br />";
```

Output

```
1507694360-37800 //the second integer number is the offset which is in seconds
1507694360-36000 //the difference of the two is 1800 seconds = 30 mins
```

Now, knowing that there is a difference between them, you can just play with it according to your need.

Comment: That's not quite what I need. I need it as an integer number, so I can check it against the open time. I thought this might work `$currentTimeQld->getTimeStamp();` but it still returns the same time as adelaide time. `Output: 1507506480 1507506480`

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I didn't consider that requirement. See the updated answer :)

Comment: Awesome this works a treat `($currentTime->getTimestamp() - $currentTime->getOffset())`
Exactly what I need. Thanks old chum. Can you please link to the documentation in your answer :)